# How to write a nested IF and RAND excel statement

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to generate a column with rows of random binary 1's and 0's in R.

In excel, I can write this in a new column as `if(rand()< $A$1,1,0)`.

Where $A$1 = 0.1.  So if any random numbers are less than 0.1, it will return 1.   As such, the results would print a column with random rows of 1 and 0.

In R, I wrote down

```
data$binary <- ifelse(runif(1,0,1)<0.1,1,0)
```

and all I'm getting is only values of 1.

If the random number generated is less than 0.1, then return 1 else 0.

Much help is appreciated!

Comment: Do: `ifelse(runif(nrow(data),0,1)<0.1,1,0)`. You want to generate as many random numbers as the number of rows.

Comment: Perfect!  This is what I was kind of envisioning.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `runif` you can use

```
n <- 10
+(runif(n,0,1) < 0.1)
```

Since `+(runif(n,0,1) < 0.1)` on an average would be 1 for 10% of `n`, you can also use `sample` with probability argument which would give you the same result.

```
sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ifelse()` is a vectorizing operator, so the output keeps the same dimensions of the condition. In your code, `runif(1,0,1)` is a single value, thus giving single-valued output when using `ifelse()`.

Maybe you should try it like below

```
df$binary <- ifelse(df$A<0.1,1,0)
```

such that

```
> df
           A binary
1  0.2875775      0
2  0.7883051      0
3  0.4089769      0
4  0.8830174      0
5  0.9404673      0
6  0.0455565      1
7  0.5281055      0
8  0.8924190      0
9  0.5514350      0
10 0.4566147      0
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = runif(10,0,1))
```

Comment: Perfect!!  This is exactly what I was trying to do.  Thank you very much!